# Can't login using Stack Exchange OpenID with Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, firefox

I cannot login to Meta with Firefox. This is the login form:

[image]

When I click `Log in using Stack Exchange` I get the following:

[image]

Neither `Email` nor `Password` field has focus. When I click one of these fields to set the focus, the `Log in using Stack Exchange` section closes, and I get the following form again:

[image]

I can reproduce the error in Firefox 26.0/Linux and Firefox 25.0/Windows. There is no problem in Chrome, Opera or IE.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 26.0 on OSX 10.7

Comment: fix in the pipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed will be with you in build rev `2014.1.16.1861`.

Comment: And the other sites? ;)

Comment: currently the new login is enabled only on the meta tier - to root out bugs like this

Comment: Now it's [broken for all browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217544/152859). :(

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround until it's fixed, follow these steps:

1. Click "More login options"
2. Type `https://openid.stackexchange.com` into the "manually enter your OpenId" textbox
3. Click  Submit and you will get the form, solid this time.

Comment: I confirm that it works. Alternatively, you can start typing your login or password in the initial form without releasing the mouse button. The section will stay open. Though the entire procedure is a bit tricky :)