# Can't login with Stack Exchange username and password

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, login

I almost always login through Stack Overflow,

[image]

but today I happened to clear my cache then go straight to Meta, which presented me with

[image]

Here, the <kbd>Log In</kbd> button does nothing for me. I *am* in an airport right now, so I tried waiting plenty (several minutes), tried multiple times, and also tried other sites concurrently to make sure it wasn't my connection. However, this button alone doesn't seem to respond.

I see an AJAX request going out for validation

[image]

but no response. All I see in the console is this, but *on page load* only:

[image]

Is anyone else able to reproduce this behavior? If not, I assume it's the airport connection. (I was able to login to post this question by logging into Stack Overflow first, then getting redirected on meta.)

Comment: Sorry! I missed the thread.

Comment: It appears that this may be a different problem.

Comment: @ChrisF it was reported as answer to the linked post but due to its severity agree it's better be reported as a standalone bug report.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217517/223030

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case of too much validation - there were bits of validation running on this page that shouldn't have - this was validation for the signup page which failed (for obvious reasons).

I focused on the error cases too much over the last few days that I completely missed the success case.

Sorry about that - this is now fixed and works as expected.